# Conjunctive testing or not in retrospective study?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, observational-study

I have a device that can estimate 2 continuous, independent quantities A and B of its users.

There is an accepted criterion for "accuracy" for each quantity A and B.

Let's say I want to prove that my device has a sufficiently good accuracy ratio for A and B. I know I have sufficiently good existing data for that. Hence, I'll want to conduct a retrospective study.

I still want to show that I control my type 2 risk, and perform a sample size computation using a separate calibration study that I have. I want a statistical power of 0.8. Should I compute the sample size for A and B separately since this is all retrospective, or should I use a conjunctive test ?

On the one hand, using a conjunctive test seems more logical since I know I'll use the same dataset for both measures. On the other hand, if we do that, why not include in the conjunction any other metric that my device outputs, in particular a metric C that the dataset was built for ?